# Twilio node not functioning properly gives me an error self._form.on is not a function

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I'm running a react app and in it I'm trying to execute an sms from twilio.
In a component:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.twilioSend();
}

//twilio credentials
const accountSid = 'Imasidnumber';
const authToken = 'Imanauthtoken';
const twilio = require('twilio');
const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

    export function twilioSend() {
      client.messages.create({
        body: 'hello from node',
        to: '+13105551212',
        from: '+15625551212'
      })
      .then((message) => console.log(message.sid))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
```

Very simple and straight forward.
When I load my component I get this error:

```
×
TypeError: self._form.on is not a function
Request.push../node_modules/request/request.js.Request.form
node_modules/request/request.js:1252
  1249 | }
  1250 | // create form-data object
  1251 | self._form = new FormData()
> 1252 | self._form.on('error', function (err) {
       | ^  1253 |   err.message = 'form-data: ' + err.message
  1254 |   self.emit('error', err)
  1255 |   self.abort()
```

There's a couple of references to this error on a few more questions on SO but honestly they're not very helpful.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend against using the Twilio Server-Side SDKs on the client side, since you will be exposing your authentication credentials.

You can create this functionality on the backend. Here is an example using Express.

Welcome to the JavaScript Guild!

https://github.com/twilio/starter-node

[Is Someone Else Using Your Twilio Account? Best Practices to Protect Your Auth Token](https://www.twilio.com/blog/protect-phishing-auth-token-fraud)